# When I run truffle compile I get a ParserError: syntax error

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-compile

**Error i'm getting back when I run truffle compile**

> ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'contract'

**How my contract looks:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol"

contract SomeContract is ERC721{

   using Counters for Counters.Counter;
       Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
       mapping(string => uint8) hashes;

   constructor() public ERC721("SomeContract", "SMC") {}

   function awardItem(address recipient, string memory hash, string memory metadata)
   public
   returns (uint256)
   {
       require(hashes[hash] != 1);
       hashes[hash] = 1;
       _tokenIds.increment();
       uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
       _mint(recipient, newItemId);
       _setTokenURI(newItemId, metadata);
       return newItemId;
   }
}
```

**My environment**

- Truffle v5.3.1
- solidity 0.6.0
- nodejs V15
- web3 v1.3.5

It must have something to do with the versions of Truffle I am using with Solidity but I tried uninstalling and installing the packages but doesn't seem to work. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Your second import statement is missing the `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `;` in import

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol"
```

should be :

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
```

Moreover, use `^0.8.0` because openzepplin contracts are compiled in it and use @openzeppelin/contracts 3.0 (npm) as `_setTokenURI` is not available in v4 (replaced by other function)

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that. Yeah _setTokenURI is given me an Undeclared identifier error now, but I see in the docs https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc721 they're still using it.

Comment: Here's a link to an answer for the question above, that might work for someone else, didn't work for me though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66789290/declarationerror-undeclared-identifier-although-its-present-in-erc721-sol